# React Leaflet: How to have Multiselect on Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, multi-select, react-leaflet

I'm using React and React-Leaflet to generate a map of circleMarkers given data points and their Lat/Long coordinates. I have no issues rendering a map of data, and even being able to change the data rendered if a user filters by filter type on a sidebar.

```
<Map center={[this.props.data[0].Latitude, this.props.data[0].Longitude]} zoom={12}>
    <TileLayer
      attribution="&amp;copy <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
      url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    />

    /* code for rendering circleMarkers goes here */

</Map>
```

When a user clicks on a marker, I have it so a popup appears on the map for the data with a little blurb about the corresponding point.

```
<CircleMarker center={[entry.Latitude, entry.Longitude]} color={this.determineMarkerColor(entry)} radius={this.computeMarkerSize(entry)}>
          <Popup>
              <span>Radius is for: {this.props.filterType} </span>
          </Popup>
</CircleMarker>
```

Is there a way to configure the Map so that it can figure out when a user is trying to, for example, shift click to select multiple points and then pass the selected points as an array? Or, even better, how can I make the Map interactive so a user can drag and drop a custom area (like drawing a square or circle) and select all rendered points WITHIN that area?

I'm planning on passing this array of selected data to another component that will graph it.

Any advice on where to look for this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could play around with [leaflet-draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) in order to get the selection tool that you want. With leaflet-draw you can draw polygons, circles, rectangles, etc and get the bounds of the figure you've drawn. There's also a library called [point-in-polygon](https://github.com/substack/point-in-polygon) that can return the coordinates inside a boundaries parameter.

**TLDR**:

1. Draw polygon with Leaflet Draw and get the bounds of your drawn figure.
2. Filter your markers that have their {latitude, longitude} inside the bounds with Point-in-polygon.

Comment: Ah I didn't know about leaflet-draw. Just googled and found react-leaflet-draw (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-draw). Will check it out and see if it works, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad to help! Normally leaflet draw is used to draw polygons and areas on maps not to select markers but since you can get the bounds of your draw I guess it could be used to select markers with a bit of tweaking.

Answer (score 5):

It's already almost 3 years passed away but here is my solution with pressing shift and selecting an area of markers, maybe it will be useful for somebody

`Map` has `onmousedown` & `onmouseup` methods

```
<Map
  ref={saveMap}
  onmousedown={onMouseDown} // set start position in state
  onmouseup={onMouseUp} // end position and logic to select markers
  className="leaflet-container"
  center={position}
  zoom={viewport.zoom}
>
```

With `onmousedown` it is possible to find the `start position` when the user pressed shift and started to move the mouse to select an area

`onmousedown` returns an event with `latlng` property - start position:

```js
const onMouseDown = useCallback((e: LeafletMouseEvent) => {
  if (e.originalEvent.shiftKey) { // check if the shift key been pressed
    setStartPoint(e.latlng);
  }
}, []);
```

`onmouseup` also returns an event with `latlng` property - end position:

```js
const onMouseUp = useCallback((e: LeafletMouseEvent) => {
  if (e.originalEvent.shiftKey && startPoint) {
    const bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(startPoint, e.latlng); // creates a class which will help to identify if an element is within the selection boundaries
    const selectedIds: string[] = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < orders?.length; i++) {
      const { geometry: { coordinates } } = orders[i];
      const point = new L.LatLng(coordinates[0], coordinates[1]);
      bounds.contains(point) && selectedIds.push(orders[i].properties.entry);
    }
    onSelectOrder(selectedIds);
    setStartPoint(null);
  }
}, [onSelectOrder, orders, startPoint]);
```

It works pretty well for my purposes to select multiple orders on the map

Comment: This solution worked for me! Thank you so much for sharing. How did you disable the zoom effect?